# consider if the number is negative or positive

Tags: algebra-precalculus

We have number $\displaystyle a= - \sum_{1\le}\sum_{i<j}\sum_{<k\le n} a_ia_ja_k + \sum_{1\le}\sum_{i<j}\sum_{<k < p}\sum_{\le n} a_ia_ja_ka_p - \cdots \pm a_ia_ja_ka_p\cdots a_n $

When $n$ is a even then the last sign is $+$, when it's odd then it's $-$ and we have all $a \in[0,1]$

Comment: What's your question? Do you want to know if $a$ is positive?

Comment: yes exactly, I guess $a$ is negative but I don't know how to prove it

Comment: Where did you got this problem from? It seems interesting.

Comment: It isn't task from any book I just wanted to check if my approach to challenge question given by my teacher have any probability to sucess